# .load() issue when adding selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having an issue loading html after a click event and then performing an animation on the new element. When I add a selector suffix to the load call the html doesn't load, but the event handler returns "success." Without the selector appended the html loads but then I have no way to select it with jquery.

Html:

```
<button id="btn-click">Click me</button>
<div id="placeholder"></div>
```

JS:

```
$("#btn-click").click( function () {
    $("#placeholder").load("dynamicContent.html #new-content", function () {
        $("#new-content").css( "color", "red");
    });
});
```

dynamicContent.html

```
<p>just some text for now.</p>
```

This wont load the new file at all. Is there a reason this might be happening?

Comment: what file do you actually want to load? `dynamicContent.html` or `new-contnet.html`?

Comment: My mistake, edited for consistency

Comment: what are you trying to do with the hash in the url?

Comment: It's no surprise, the content you are trying to load doesn't have an element with ID `new-content`, so there is nothing to load for jQuery.

Comment: according to the jQuery docs it will "load the content of the element with id="p1", inside the file "demo_test.txt", into a specific <div> element." Unless I'm misunderstanding it will load the content into a div with the id="new-content"

Comment: Read again: *"load the content **of** the element with id="p1", inside the file "demo_test.txt"* It doesn't load the content *in* an element with that ID. `.load` always adds the content to the element that is selected, so in your case `#placeholder`.

Comment: @Josh: jQuery will search the loaded file for the selector you passed (`#new-content`) and only append that element.  Otherwise, it appends the entire file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I have explained in my comment, the content you are trying to load doesn't have an element with ID `new-content`, so there is nothing to load for jQuery.

Your new content contains a `p` element, so if you want to target that one, simply `.find` it:

```
$("#btn-click").click( function () {
    $("#placeholder").load("dynamicContent.html", function () {
        $(this).find('p').css( "color", "red");
    });
});
```

Inside the `.load` callback, `this` refers to the selected element, and you can use any [traversal method](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/) to find the elements you want to manipulate.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you, you want to load new content then do something with that content. It may work like this:

```
("#btn-click").click( function () {
    $("#placeholder").load("dynamicContent.html", function () {
        $(this).find("#new-content").css( "color", "red");
        //or: $("#new-content", this).css( "color", "red");
    });
});
```

According to jQuery doc: "If a "complete" callback is provided, it is executed after post-processing and HTML insertion has been performed." So within the complete function you should be able to access the new content with the above or: `$("#new-content", this)`

**update**

On re-reading the question, if you want to change the color on the `<p>` that is in the loaded HTML, get to it like `$("p", this).css( "color", "red");`.

If you want to change the color on the entire placeholder, then use this: `$(this).css( "color", "red");`